# Prove the following statement: if $ab$ is odd, then $a^2 + b^2$ is even

Tags: number-theory

I am having a hard time with this one although it looks easy.
Prove the following statement:
Suppose a,b are integers. If $ab$ is odd, then $a^2 + b^2$ is even.

I know I might need to use the fact that $a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab$.
Can someone please tell me where to start?

Answer (score 2):

If $ab$ is odd, both $a$ and $b$ must be odd (all other possibilities give even). Then $a^2$ is product of two odd numbers, so is odd. Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 2):

What you Need is:
$$\text{For} \ a,b \in \mathbb N: ab \text{ is odd}  \Leftrightarrow a \text{ is odd and } b \text{ is odd.}$$